# Closeness of a set in a infinite dimensional Hibert Space and projection of $0$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

I began to read Clarke's Nonsmooth Analysis and the first exercise in chapter is

Let $X$ be a real Hilbert space that admits a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and set
$$
S := \left\{ \frac{1+i}{i}e_i : i\geq1 \right\}.
$$
Prove that $S$ is closed, and that $\text{proj}_S(0) = \emptyset$.

1. For the closeness, $S_k:=\left\{ \frac{1+i}{i}e_i : 1\leq i\leq k \right\}$ with $1\leq k $ is closed (since it is a discrete set) then $S=\bigcup_{k\geq1}S_k$ is closed.

Now, for the projection (defined by the set of points that the distance of $0$ to $S$ is minimal) , how can this set be empty ? I mean, shouldn't it exist a point in $S$ that the distance to $0$ is the smallest then every other point in $S$?

Comment: An infinite union of closed subsets is not necessarily closed. E.g. in $\Bbb R:$ $\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}[1/n,1]=(0,1].$

Comment: Which real number in $\{1/n\}$ is the smallest one?

Comment: $d(0,\frac{1+i}ie_i)=?$

Comment: @AnneBauval, sure but in this case $S_1=\{2 e_1 \}$, $S_2=\{2 e_1, 1.5 e_2 \}$ ... and $e_i$ is the ith element of the base. It is the case that $S_k$ is a discrete set right?

Comment: $S_k$ is discrete for all $k$, but that doesn't mean their union is closed. For an example, consider $A_k = \{(i+1)/i: i\in \mathbb N, 1\le i \le k\}$. Each $A_k$ is discrete and therefore closed, but their union, $A=\{(i+1)/i: i\in \mathbb N\}$ is *not* closed. $1\notin A$, but there is no neighborhood of $1$ disjoint from $A$. Now, the set $S$ actually is closed, but you'll need to show that unlike $A$ it doesn't have any points like that.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, $e_i$ is base element right? So each $S_k$ adds another dimensions for the set and for each dimensions there is only one element, I'm having problem on how to construct the sequences to show that every accumulation point is in $S$